# Is it possible to use 2 WDS for 2 different users roles in 1 JMeter Thread group?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, wds

There are 2 users roles in Application.

When running 2 users roles sequentially in 1 browser (login1 - actions1 - logout1, login2 - actions2 - logout2), the set of problems with users identity /pages visibility and fails occurs.

Is it possible to use 1 dedicated browser window for each user role in 1 JMeter Thread group?

Or what could be solution to split 2 users for 2 separate browsers and manage them as 1 group acting sequentially, role1 actions first and then role2 actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"the set of problems with users identity /pages visibility and fails occurs" - it should not be the case given well-behaved script, just in case try executing the following line after the "logout"

```
WDS.browser.manage().deleteAllCookies()
```

More information: [WebDriver.Options.deleteAllCookies()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html#deleteAllCookies())

Another option is to put conditions into your script like:

```
if (WDS.ctx.getThreadNum() == 0) {
    // code specific for user 1
}


if (WDS.ctx.getThreadNum() == 1) {
    // code specific for user 2
}
```

Where `WDS.ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)

And last but not the least, you can just put your users into different Thread Groups, just tick `Run Thread Groups consecutively` box on [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level:

[image]

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)

Comment: Thank you. I checked WDS.browser.manage().deleteAllCookies() - even with that line, incognito mode in Chrome after 1st user logout keeps information about this previous user (Application->Storage) or it could be seen in login form which appears with previous user name and option "use another account"... Chromedriver v90. Could it be driver version specific problem?

Comment: Variant3 with separate Thread groups for 2 client-side users works, however I have server-side Thread group, which should work in parallel with both client-side users...

Comment: If logout doesn't clear local storage it sounds like an application bug and should be reproducible for real user using the real browser. If you need a workaround - I believe `WDS.browser.getSessionStorage().clear()` and `WDS.browser.getLocalStorage().clear()` should help you

Comment: thank you for assortiment of ideas and solutions and your time. Looks like last presupposition took place, even after adding clear commands some misbehave occured.